# Перевод функции на php

Tags: php

Святослав Семеркин:
Есть такая функция на Пыхе, очень хочу получить её Си или Go вариант. Чтобы это не выглядело тупо "сделайте за меня", подскажите пожалуйста что происходит в строчках отмеченных восклицательными знаками в комментах

```
 function mixer($key,$id) {
   preg_match_all("/[\da-f]+/",$key,$pre); //!
   $pre = $id%2==0 ? array_reverse($pre[0]) : $pre[0]; //!
   $mixed = join('',$pre); //!
   $s = strlen($mixed);
   $r='';
   for($k=0; $k&lt;$s; ++$k) { //!
       if ($k%3==0) {
           $r .= substr($mixed,$k,1); //!
       }
   }
   return $r;
}
```

Comment: Чтобы это не выглядело тупо «сделайте за меня», расскажите, что именно вы не понимаете в этом коде и какие именно затруднения со строками, отмеченными восклицательными знаками?

Comment: 1)Ну вот например переменная pre. Это вообще что за сущность? Она появляется в preg_match_all впервые в качестве аргумента.

Comment: 2) в цикле фор не могу понять условие: $k&lt; $s.

Comment: И вообще главный вопрос, при условии что на вход функции дам key и id, этого хватит для её выполнения? При запуске функции мне выдаётся ошибка, хотя я ее взял с блога одного уважаемого человека

Comment: `&lt;` это вы уже криво скопировали откуда-то, там явно должно быть `<`

Comment: А на 1) вы вполне найдёте ответ в документации http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match-all.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $pre это результат работы preg_match_all()
2. если $id четное число, то в переменную $pre, вернется массив $pre с элементами в обратном порядке
3. $k<$s; - ошибка копирования =) имелось ввиду "<"
4. разбирает строку $mixed, начинающийся с символа $k, длиной в один символ